# How to remove Accessibility shortcut option from my Accessibility app?

Tags: android-permissions, android-10.0, android-11, accessibility

I have an AccessibilityService that will break if the user turns it on and off through the Android system user interface. I only want the user to be able to disable/enable AccessibilityService through my own Activity which will handle shutting it on and off correctly.

I never encountered this feature before until I tested my app on newer devices. On Android 11 devices there is suddenly an option to toggle "Accessibility Shortcut". This will add a button at the bottom corner the navigation buttons OR it will allow the user to toggle the AccessibilityService by holding both volume buttons at the same time. For my app, it say's it will add the toggle near the navigation buttons.

How do I remove this option?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am running into the exact same problems. Users tend to enable all switch button they see without reading explanation or videos. Since accessibility shortcut interfere in a bad way with the accessibility service, they got a non working experience.

It seems at first sight there is no option for developpers to hide the option for their accesibility services...